# SQL Server 2014 INSERT trigger not firing (not sending mail)

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, database-trigger

The trigger I am using is not firing, any ideas/help is appreciated. I checked the sysmail_allitems and its empty. To give some more explanation, I have a program where we submit travel requests through a form, when you submit a form a new row is created in TS_CUSTOM_TRVLBCK, everytime this happens I want an email to be sent with the conditions below. I have submitted a new form form (added image), the row is there but the trigger didnt fire.

My goal is to receive an email when one of the users in the where statement submits a request (a new row is created)

[image]

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TS_TRAVEL_NEW_IIS]
ON [dbo].[TS_CUSTOM_TRVLBCK]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @user Varchar(100)
    DECLARE @subject Varchar(100)
    DECLARE @body Varchar (200)

    SELECT @user  + RTRIM(TRVL_INITIATOR) FROM inserted;

    SET @subject = 'New Travel Request - ' + @user
    SET @body = 'Kindky note that user ' + @user + ' has submitted a new travel request.'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE [TRVL_INITIATOR] IN ('Luke Gatt','Marcelle Attard','Matthew Borg Dingli','Mark Schembri','Fiona Tesi','Charmaine Buttigieg','Stephen Mifsud','Tessabelle Cammilleri'))
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'luke.gatt@mca.org.mt', 
          @profile_name = 'AbsenceMailer',
          @subject = @subject,
          @body = @body;
    END
END

GO
```

Comment: I suggest against using `sp_send_dbmail` in a trigger. Put the data in a table, and then have a separate process email the details. If, for whatever reason, your email fails to send (maybe your email server is down, you have a time out error, etc) then your `INSERT` statement will be rolled back as well.

Comment: Also, your trigger assumes only 1 row will ever be inserted at a time. It shouldn't.

Comment: These are valid points however I still do not know why my code is not working.

Comment: I'm  happy to help and change it. Firstly, where does the value of `@user` come from? You `DECLARE` it, but never assign a value to it. You also use a `SELECT` on it (`SELECT @user  + RTRIM(TRVL_INITIATOR) FROM inserted;`), however, using a `SELECT` statement to return a dataset in a trigger is deprecated and should be avoided. That statement, also, will simply returns a dataset of `NULL`s as `NULL + {anything} = NULL`.

Comment: I thought the SELECT statement was putting the TRVL_INITIATOR value into @user and then using the name in the subject and body. In this case shouldn't the trigger fire anyway and send an empty/null email?

Comment: `SELECT @user  + RTRIM(TRVL_INITIATOR) FROM inserted;` dones't assign anything, it's not an assignment statement. `SELECT @user = RTRIM(TRVL_INITIATOR) FROM inserted;` would be the correct syntax, however, that still assumes that there is only ` row in `inserted`. Could you update your post to provide details of your full goal please?

Comment: It worked, thanks, I guess it does not fire will null values.

Comment: so you're *happy* that your trigger won't work correctly if you `INSERT` more than one row at the same time...? (I wouldn't be).